# How to check if a certificate matches a private key in spring boot api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot API, the client is passing a certificate in the header. How do I check if that certificate matches a private key on the API side? I am trying to do cert-based authentication. My scenario is as mentioned in [Spring boot x509 testing - pcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53315857/spring-boot-x509-testing-pcf). In Cloud Foundry my client certificate is forwarded to my spring boot API and needs to read out the header and validate the cert against the private if valid allow access. Any help is appreciated

Thanks